# CakePHP - Directories in tmp directory deleted

Tags: linux, cakephp, centos

Something strange happened to my website. This is actually the 2nd time: All directories under the tmp directory under /var/www/html/app/tmp/ were deleted with no reason. I woke up on a call stating that the site is down and upon investigating, found that all directories under tmp were deleted.

The site is hosted on a CentOS Server

Any ideas?
Regards
John

Comment: what users have write access to the folders?

Comment: root and apache users